# How google will identify origin of request (Google sign-in)

Tags: httprequest, google-signin

I am developing a website, I wanted to include Google Sign-in. So I created a project in **console.developers.google.com**. I saw below paragraph there.

***Authorized JavaScript origins**

For use with requests from a browser. This is the origin URI of the client application. It can't contain a wildcard (https://*.example.com) or a path (https://example.com/subdir). If you're using a nonstandard port, you must include it in the origin URI.*

I want to know how Google will be able to identify domain that originated the request?

If possible I want to know, is it possible to check if request is made from browser or not?

How Google will determine if I sent a request from browser/NodeJs/rest api client (like Postman)? I am asking this because before creating client credentials we have to select origin of request, how will Google identify the origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know how Google will be able to identify domain that originated the request?

Browsers send [an Origin header](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#origin-request-header) when making cross-origin requests using JavaScript APIs which would allow the JavaScript to read the response.

> If possible I want to know, is it possible to check if request is made from browser or not?

Not reliably. Any custom client could send a set of headers identical to that of a browser.

> How Google will determine if I sent a request from browser/NodeJs/rest api client (like Postman)?

It won't, but this shouldn't matter. The goal is to block malicious third parties. If **you** send the request from Postman (or whatever) then the request is still being sent by you, so there is no third party, just you and Google.

Answer (score 0):

All the info you are asking about will be found in the request headers.

For example, to know the request is made by browser or not, you can check the

```
header: user-agent
sample value: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
```

The origin of the request can be found in the `origin` header. You might be surprised that the referrer of the request is also recorded in the headers.